# Reconnecting to socket.io server takes long time after receiving messages using SocketIoClientDotNet

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket, socket.io, grasshopper

I'm developing a plugin for Grasshopper for Rhino which uses a .NET framework with C# and I have a problem when reconnecting to a socket.io 1.4.5 server. I'm using [SocketIoClientDotNet 0.9.13](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) to connect to a server and it works fine if I just want to connect/disconnect to a server but I have a problem reconnecting to a server after I received a message using an event taking a lot of time to reconnect.

Depends on the number of messages I received by the event during the connection, after I close and make a new connection it takes more than a minute (sometimes more than 10 mins if there are a lot of messages received) for the new connection.

Could anybody tell what is going wrong?

The code is written as follows:

```
Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket socket;

private System.Threading.ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = null;
private bool currentState = false;
public object output = null;
public bool connected = false;

private Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.IO.Options CreateOptions()
{
  Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.IO.Options op = new Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.IO.Options();
  op.AutoConnect = true;
  op.Reconnection = true;
  op.ReconnectionAttempts = 5;
  op.ReconnectionDelay = 5;
  op.Timeout = 20;
  op.Secure = true;
  op.ForceNew = true;
  op.Multiplex = true;
  return op;
}

private void ConnectToSocket(bool b, string address){
  if(currentState != b){
    if(b && !connected){
        manualResetEvent = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

        var options = CreateOptions();
        socket = IO.Socket(address, options);

        socket.On(Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
          {

          connected = true;
          Print("connected");
          manualResetEvent.Set();
          });

        socket.On("slider_message", (data) =>
          {
          if(data != null){
            var jobject = data as JToken;
            try{
              var sliderValue = jobject.Value<string>("slider");
              output = sliderValue;
            }catch{

            }
          }

          manualResetEvent.Set();
          });
     
        socket.On(Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, () =>
          {

          connected = false;
          Print("disconnected");

          manualResetEvent.Set();
          });

        Print("connecting...");

        manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
    }else{
      if(socket != null & connected){
        manualResetEvent = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

        Print("disconnecting...");
        socket.Close();

        manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
        socket = null;
      }
    }
  }

  currentState = b;
}
```